# Как сделать что-то по типу шторки?

Tags: android

`RecyclerView` состоит из элементов, которые в свою очередь тоже содержат `RecyclerView`(я буду называть его подсписок). Чтобы подсписок не нагромождал экран, я хочу чтобы он разворачивался и сворачивался по нажатию на кнопку. Не могу сообразить что мне для этого использовать, подскажите пожалуйста!

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно по разному сделать. Имхо, лучше вместо добавления ещё одного RecyclerView добавить в уже имеющийся новый тип ячейки и изменять список данных адаптера по нажатию на свернуть/развернуть.

Comment: Типа разворачивающийся список? Может подойдет expandablelistview?

Comment: Спасибо, думаю expandablelistview подойдет.